# Unit testing controllers with ScalaTest in Play! framework

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.2, scalatest

I'm working with Play 2.2 and ScalaTest. It's the first time I'm trying to test a controller in my play application. I do it this way:

```
class TestArtistController extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  "ArtistController" must {

    "returns artists" in new WithApplication {
      val eventuallyResult = controllers.ArtistController.findNearCity("lyon")(FakeRequest())
      whenReady(eventuallyResult, timeout(Span(2, Seconds))) { result =>
        println(result.body) //it is an Enumerator[Array[Byte]]
        result.header.status mustBe 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It allows me to correctly test the return result but I don't know how to test the body of the result. `result.body` returns an `Enumerator[Array[bytes]]` and I totally don't know how I could transform it to retrieve the `Json` that I'm sending.

What is the good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `play.api.test.Helpers._` and use helper functions such as `contentAsJson(res)` or `status(res)`, with `res` being the result of your action (you may need to use `res.run` in some cases for async actions).